# Regular expression for remove last n characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a requirement to remove last n characters from string or remove 'page' from a particular string. 
Eg:

```
var string = 'facebookpage';

Expected output string = 'facebook'
```

I would like to remove 'page' from the string.

Done it using substring.

```
var str = "facebookpage";
str = str.substring(0, str.length - 4);
```

Could you help me to find some better way to do it.

Comment: If you specifically want to remove "page" you can use `replace`: `var str = str.replace('page', '')`, otherwise there probably isn't a simpler method.

Comment: that is better way. although through regex `str.replace(\w{4}$, ""); `

Comment: I think substring is better than regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regex for this:

```
//str - string;
//n - count of symbols, for return 
function(str, n){
  var re = new RegExp(".{" + n + "}","i");
  return str.match(re);
};
```

**EDIT:**

For remove last n characters:

```
var re = new RegExp(".{" + n + "}$","i");
return str.replace(re, "");
```

**UPDATE:**
But use regex for this task, not good way; For example, AVG Runtime for 100000 iterations:

```
Str length solution = 63.34 ms
Regex solution      = 172.2 ms
```

Comment: You're missing `$` for the end of the string.

Comment: @Olson.dev Nope. 1st variant - return from 0 to n position; But thanks, You gave me the idea, for how to remove exactly last n symbols;

Comment: Your original answer didn't answer the OP, your EDIT does. Passing the flag "i" is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript replace function

```
 var str = "facebookpage";
 str = str.replace('page','');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regular expression :

```
(.*)\\w{4}
```

code :

```
var regex =(new RegExp("(.*)\\w{4}"))
val output = regex .exec("facebookpage")
// output is : ["facebookpage", "facebook"]
// output[1] is the Expected output which you want.
```

Hope this helps.